# Where is the "Include C++ support" option in android studio 3.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.3

I am a novice at android development, and I am following some tutorials to practice.

I notice that in several tutorials there is always a "Include C++ support" option when they are creating a new project. like in this image:

[image]

However, when it comes to Android studio 3.3 (which is the latest version, and I just installed it yesterday), I just can't find it. Android studio 3.3 is like this:
[image]

I have tried to google something like "android studio 3.3 include C++ support", but failed to get an answer.

**So, where is that option? Did they abandon it?**

**By the way, I am developing on linux (Ubuntu16.04), while most tutorials I found are on windows. Could this be a reason?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, In android studio 3.3 it has been changed and now it comes under **New>New Project>Choose your project** scroll down and you will find something called **Native C++**, as show in below image,

[image: Include C]

[Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#new-project)